# changing value of input-button using parent's id

Tags: jquery

How can I change value of input [button] using parent's id, in jQuery
Also, I need to set css to display: block

Any help guys?

```
<div id="upload_file" style="display: none;">

     <input type="button" value="Add New File">

</div>
```

Comment: you want to change button's values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SneWa/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#upload_file>input:button").val("New Value");
```

See it working at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/ZnuDT/1/)

To display the element you'll need:

```
$("#upload_file").show();
```

This sets the default CSS display style for the element. If you want to force 'block', try

```
$("#upload_file").css("display","block");
```

You can of course chain it into a single operation:

```
$("#upload_file").show().children("input:button").val("New Value");
```

This can be seen in action at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/ZnuDT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
     $("button").attr('value', 'new value');
     $("#upload_file").show();
}
```